# Finding Agent Job using SSIS package name

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms

Stuck in a dilemma, I need to find the ***Agent Job*** that runs a specific SSIS package. A former coworker of mine was responsible for about half of the 200 or so agent jobs we have (some using multiple packages). His naming scheme is subpar at best and I need to locate the **ONE** job that runs a specific package to populate a single table.

Comment: Maybe research over on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ If you want to ask here, you should provide your query as a [mcve].

Comment: Hi @arrchar, was your question addressed?. If so, can you please mark it as answered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the package name is known the job that runs it can be located via jobstep table:

```
SELECT sj.name, s.command FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps s
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj ON s.job_id = sj.job_id
WHERE command LIKE '%packagename.dtsx%'
```